# How are FIFA 14 Ultimate Team squad ratings determined?

Tags: fifa-14

I've noticed in my Ultimate Team squad that the overall team rating is well below the average of the ratings of each individual player. My team's chemistry is at 100% so this is not a factor.

Does anyone know how these ratings are determined?

Comment: Are you including the subs and reserves?

Comment: Yes, simply moving a player from bench to active squad will make an impact on its rating if the difference between the replaced player is large enough, so there is something else going on here. Perhaps a weighted system.